# How can I find if an exe file is installation executable or not?

Tags: c#

How can I find if an exe file is a setup file or not?

For example:

```
bool isSetupFile = IsSetup(@"C:\KasperSkySetup.exe");
```

Regards.

Comment: Hard to tell since there are so many install frameworks. You could target a few, like MSI, or ZIPSFX, etc., but it will be a lot of custom code and not very accurate.  Setup files are just programs like anything else.

Comment: I find your requirements unsatisfactory sir, move back one step in the process!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It'd require a very complex and error-prone heuristic to tell whether an executable is an installation package or not.
In general, the answer is no, you cannot do that.

Additional reading:
[Link](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100726-00/?p=13323)

Answer (score 1):

A setup file could be created by anyone and is a program like any other. But you could probably find some common header bytes for the files if they are created by a popular installer program like Wise.

Information on installer programs (not .msi based) can be found at: http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/tt_nonmsi.htm

Comment: Thanks for the useful link. But it seems that inspecting/covering all of the setup file formats is practically impossible.